# Help me optimise this method please

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

It's a fairly straightforward operation - I'm placing 'handles' at regular points of a DisplayObjectContainer. These handles will be used to scale, rotate a la Illustrator, etc.

I know this can be done with some fairly simple maths but I spent all my maths lessons drawing stick-men dying in increasingly creative ways.

TargetW/targetH are the original width/height of the object I'm adding the handles to. Obviously, adding the handles increases width/height so they are stored beforehand.

```
protected function positionHandles():void {

        handles[0].x = 0;
        handles[0].y = 0;

        handles[1].x = targetW / 2;
        handles[1].y = 0;

        handles[2].x = targetW;
        handles[2].y = 0;

        handles[3].x = 0;
        handles[3].y = targetH / 2;

        handles[4].x = targetW / 2;
        handles[4].y = targetH / 2;

        handles[5].x = targetW;
        handles[5].y = targetH / 2;

        handles[6].x = 0;
        handles[6].y = targetH;

        handles[7].x = targetW / 2;
        handles[7].y = targetH;

        handles[8].x = targetW;
        handles[8].y = targetH;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected function positionHandles():void {

    for(var n:int = 0; n < 9; n ++) {
       handles[n].x = [0, targetW / 2, targetW][n % 3];
       handles[n].y = [0, targetH / 2, targetH][int(n / 3)];
    }

}
```

Comment: That's the one. Any idea how to modify this so that it works when the reg. point is in the middle, rather than top-left?

Comment: `[-targetW/2, 0, targetW/2]` and `[-targetH/2, 0, targetH/2]` would work. I think. However I would be tempted to calculate the rectangle of the object outside of the loop and then use this: `[left, (left+right)/2, right]` and `[top, (top+bottom)/2, bottom]`. That way the registration point can be wherever without affecting the loop.

Comment: Cool, that'd be a very useful feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
var targetWidth:Number = 100;
var targetHeight:Number = 50;
var widthHandleDistance:Number = targetWidth/2;
var heightHandleDistance:Number = targetHeight/2;
var handles:Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>();

function positionHandles():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i<=targetWidth; i=i+widthHandleDistance)
    {
        for (var k:int = 0; k<=targetHeight; k=k+heightHandleDistance)
        {
            var handle:Point = new Point(i,k);
            handles.push(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can also easily adjust the amount of handles.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a set amount of handle (9) so this doesn't work.

Comment: I could just see a rounding error chopping off the rightmost/bottommost handles with this method. (Assuming targetWidth/targetHeight can be non-integer)